# Implementing __concat__ in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, sequences

I tried to implement `__concat__`, but it didn't work

```
>>> class lHolder():
...     def __init__(self,l):
...             self.l=l
...     def __concat__(self, l2):
...             return self.l+l2
...     def __iter__(self):
...             return self.l.__iter__()
... 
>>> lHolder([1])+[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'lHolder' and 'list'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__concat__` is not a special method (http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-special-method). It is part of the operator module.

You will need to implement `__add__` to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement `__add__`, not `__concat__`.  There's no `__concat__` special method in Python.